# Legend with Markers for Mesh Plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I use a mesh plot with scatter points (2d) where the colors are determined from a third coordinate of the data [as described in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33445/styled-or-fixed-color-line-segments-in-pgf/33449#33449). The legend however should contain the markers of a curve as icon (not that miniature mesh). How can I achieve that?

Edit: the problems seems to be with `legend image code` in `line legend` that does not draw correctly with mesh settings. How do I have to modify a custom `legend image code` to simply display the current marker in a fixed color (say black)?

My attempt so far

```
\pgfplotsset{
  /pgfplots/pplots legend/.style={
  legend image code/.code={   
    \draw[color=black] (0cm,0cm) to (0.6cm,0cm);
    \draw[#1,color=black,mark repeat=1,mark phase=1]
      plot coordinates {
      (0.3cm,0cm)
    };
  }}}
```

failes due to a compile error:

```
Undefined control sequence. [...] \pgfplotsplothandlermesh@numpoints ->\numcoords
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the settings above, the legend inherits the current settings of the plot (which is typically desired). In your case, you need to override the *plot handler* explicitly by providing `sharp plot` (or maybe `only marks`?) to the legend's option list:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pgfplotsset{
  /pgfplots/pplots legend/.style={
  legend image code/.code={   
    \draw[color=black] (0cm,0cm) to (0.6cm,0cm);
    \draw[sharp plot,mark=*,color=black,mark repeat=1,mark phase=1]
      plot coordinates {
      (0.3cm,0cm)
    };
  }}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[legend entries=$x^2y^2$]
    \addplot3[surf,pplots legend] {x^2*y^2};    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Are you sure that you want the `\draw[color=black] ... to ;` statement in your `legend image code`? You can probably replace it by

```
/pgfplots/pplots legend/.style={%
    /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
        \draw[mark repeat=2,mark phase=2,black,sharp plot] 
            plot coordinates {
                (0cm,0cm) 
                (0.3cm,0cm)
                (0.6cm,0cm)%
            };%
    }%
},
```

(which is the default line legend, by the way)