# pgfplots and hyperref clash for complicated figure in book class

Tags: pgfplots, sectioning, hyperref, book-design, legend

When using the book class, pgfplots, hyperref, and section labeling according to "[How to reset chapter and section counter with \part](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54383/how-to-reset-chapter-and-section-counter-with-part/123777#123777)", I get the following error

```
! You can't use `the character -' after \the.
\value ->-
          1.60942
l.51     \end{axis}
```

in the following MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book} 

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7} % to use more recent defaults

\usepackage{hyperref}

%section restarts at each part
%see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54383/how-to-reset-chapter-and-section-counter-with-part/123777#123777
\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
\pgfplotsset{
    colormap/hot,
}%
\pgfmathparse{-ln(0.1)}%
\let\BEMAX=\pgfmathresult

\pgfmathparse{-ln(5)}%
\let\BEMIN=\pgfmathresult

% FIRST: define one color for every value of \be : 
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \be in {
        0.1,
        0.5,
        0.8,
        1.0,
        2.0,
        5.0} {
    \pgfmathparse{-ln(\be)}
    \let\value=\pgfmathresult
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ylabel={$p(x)$},
        legend to name={fig:mm_temp_legend}
    ]
      \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \be/\zedd in {
                0.1/12.4595,
                0.5/18.3263,
                0.8/29.6888,
                1.0/43.0372,
                2.0/403.539,
                5.0/1.07923e6 } {
       \addplot+ gnuplot {x};
      }
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which was adapted from Christian Feuersänger's answer to "[line legend for mesh plots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106688/line-legend-for-mesh-plots)". I tried to make the example as small as possible. In particular, removing any of
`\usepackage{hyperref}`, `\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother`, `\let\value=\pgfmathresult` or `legend to name={fig:mm_temp_legend}` makes it compile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\value` is an important command of LaTeX related to counters and redefining it is a bad idea. Use `\VALUE` or some other name.

---

Note that you can simplify your construct

```
\pgfmathparse{-ln(0.1)}\let\BEMAX=\pgfmathresult
```

as

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\BEMAX{-ln(0.1)}
```

and similarly for the other alike calls.

It's also a bad idea, in my opinion, to reset chapter numbers for each part, which makes cross references very clumsy

> as we saw in chapter 2 of part III

Anyway, with the `chngcntr` package the change is easier:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}
```

With the `*` the `chapter` counter representation is not modified; it would become `\thepart.\arabic{chapter}` if the *-variant is not used.

Comment: what can I say... it's a 2 in 1 answer that should get +2! thanks. I would just add that the algorithmx package is not affected by \counterwithin, so it needs to be done manually.